# AutoMapping entities to models through an action filter attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

In **[this article](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/)**, [Jimmy Bogard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58508/jimmy-bogard) goes on to explain some of the best-practices he endorses when doing MVC.

The article in general is pretty good and I've found his advice in general (in other blog posts) to be pretty solid. However, he suggests using an attribute to map entities to models.

How is this

```
[AutoMap(typeof(Product), typeof(ShowProduct))]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var product = _productRepository.GetById(id);
    return View(product);
}
```

Any better than this (which in my opinion is way more declarative as to the actual intent of the piece of code

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var product = _productRepository.GetById(id);
    var model = Mapper.Map<Product, ShowProduct>(product);
    return View(model);
}
```

Besides that one point, there seem to be scenarios where this is rather impractical, such as action methods returning different models based on input, or even simpler scenarios such as this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return List();
    }

    public ActionResult Until(long id) // "id" is the timestamp
    {
        return List(id);
    }

    [NonAction]
    internal ActionResult List(long? timestamp = null, int count = 8)
    {
        IEnumerable<Post> posts = postService.GetLatest(timestamp, count);
        PostListModel model = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Post>, PostListModel>(posts);
        return ContextView("List", model);
    }
```

Is this actually a good practice, or just unjustified, an unwarranted obfuscation of code that was already pretty simple to begin with?

I ask out of ignorance, not personally attacking someone I regard as an awesome blogger, besides I love AutoMapper already.

Comment: He takes it even further in this video: http://www.viddler.com/v/b568679c. He creates an ActionResult that does the AutoMapping for you. His controller actions are unbelievably small. Skip forward to the ActionResults dot point to see what he does.

Comment: +1 Great questions, and resources. Is Mapper.Map<a,b> AutoMapper functionality, or is it your wrapper around it?

Comment: it's `AutoMapper`'s wrapper around their engine (it's still unit testable)

Answer (score 2):

I was doing a search on this very topic and also ran across the Los Techies post.  My next search led to this [Google Groups article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/automapper-users/M1JT-wGTqf4) in the AutoMapper-users group.

It looks like Jimmy has backed away from this guidance:

> Don't use an action filter. We went that route ourselves originally, but eventually settled on custom action results instead. It's a little
>   easier to customize those over action filters, which make it pretty
>   much impossible to supply custom behavior to.
>
> HTH,
>
> Jimmy

Comment: Here is an implementation of such ViewResult: https://github.com/jbogard/presentations/blob/master/FullSystemTesting/Code/UI/Helpers/AutoMapViewResult.cs

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts on this is that putting the mapping on the controller action is better because it lets you hide some of the details of the actual mapping implementation. You also gain additional flexibility to change the mapping in one file later on as opposed to changing this call in 7+ action methods. This assumes a purely basic, CRUD action. There might be special use cases where this doesn't work and doing something different in those cases is fine to me.

That's just my 2 cents.